# how do i get greek characters in my database using jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc, character-encoding, insert

i'm trying to insert some greek names in a database using a jsp programme. However, the result in the database is simply "????" instead of greek characters. If I try to insert a greek name using phpmyadmin or the command line, then there is no problem. So I guess there is some trouble in my jsp code. Here is a simple part of my code:

try

```
    {
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;autoReconnect=true";
    Connection con =(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root", "");
    con.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    stmt.executeQuery("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
    stmt.executeQuery("SET CHARACTER SET 'UTF8'");        
    String greekname = "κωνσταντίνα";
    stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO users(name,age) VALUES ('" + greekname + "','" + "44" +"')");
    con.close();
        }catch( Exception e ) {System.out.println("Problem during the connection with the database!");}
```

I hope someone has a good idea about it!

Comment: see this http://jnkjava.blogspot.com/2007/10/greek-and-java.html could it be the issue?

Comment: @Voooza thanks for the article, but no solution worked! From what i can see the problem is in the command "stmt.executeUpdate(...)" because it doesn't understand greek. The same happens in commands such as stmt.executeQuery. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

> *However, the result in the database is simply "????" instead of greek characters*

The database table will do that when it retrieves characters which are not covered by the character encoding which the database table is been instructed to store the characters with. You need to ensure that the database and table is created as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name CHARACTER SET utf8;
CREATE TABLE users (...) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#Databases)

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, loading the driver on *every* query is unnecessary. Just only once during application's startup is enough. Also, closing of resources should happen in `finally` block, else you risk resource leaks in case of exceptions. Finally, writing raw Java code in a JSP file is not the best practice as well ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it didn't work. The problem seems to be in the stmt.executeUpdate() command because it doesn't get greek. Any ideas for this??

Comment: If the DB already understands UTF-8, then the only thing left is the JDBC driver and JDBC URL. I checked your JDBC URL once again and `useEncoding` is actually wrong. It should have been `useUnicode`. See also the "See also" link.

Answer (score 0):

The link in the first answer solved the problem for me. It was the connect string to
the database. I was using just

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name
```

but adding the rest solved the problem.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Thanks.

Pat